# Display html text as html

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, visual-studio-2010

There's a moment in my page where I connect to a database and retrieve some data. One field in special is html code. I want to display it in my page as html inside some control that understands it. 
What are my options?

Comment: Define "understands it".

Comment: I want to: 1-retrieve html code stored in the database; 2-Put this code inside a control that parses the html and shows it.

Comment: Hey man, I'm not this kind of dev. I wanna try something, but I don't know what to use to do what I wanna do. There is probably some control that does this parsing to me, but I can't find it. I don't want you to give me the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a literal.

.aspx:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="myLiteral" />
```

codebehind:

```
myLiteral.Text = "<h2> this is a h2 html tag</h2>";
```

this will print out

### This is a h2 html tag

Comment: Very simple and exactly what I needed. Thank you.